# Git pushing to heroku rejected (non-fast-forward updates)

Tags: git, node.js, heroku

I tried going back to a previous commit on git. Now I'm trying to push it back to heroku.

```
git push staging-heroku staging:master

To git@heroku.com:MyApp.git
 ! [rejected]        staging -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:MyApp.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

I searched Stackoverflow and they're saying

```
git push -f git@heroku.com:<heroku repo name>.git
```

I tried that and I get

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)


 !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:MyApp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@MyApp.git'
```

## Update

Winfield's suggesting checking my Procfile

```
cat Procfile

web: node app.js
```

git add Procfile and git push -f git@heroku.com:MyApp.git gives me the same error message.

Comment: I'd guess you'll need to make a new commit that backs out the old change then and push that. If that's not trivial you can always e.g. use [git reparent](https://github.com/MarkLodato/git-reparent) to add a new copy of the commit you want on top of any other commit.

Comment: Thanks, Rup! I'll try learning more about reparent.

Comment: git branch gives me Develop, Master, and Staging. Would I just type git reparent staging? Do I need to install anything to make reparent work? Git's saying it's not a command.

Comment: Oh, I don't know sorry. I know git but I don't know how Heroku sets up its git repositories and there's probably some magic I don't really understand. I'd guess back out the commit somehow and push as normal, but how that translates into Heroku branches I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

The current error you're seeing is the Heroku Ruby buildpack failing to identify and integrate with a Ruby application from your git repo.

This means you are missing one or more of the following:

- `Gemfile` with gem depdencies and ruby version
- `Procfile` with one or more ruby processes to run

Comment: Thanks. So I need to add the Procfile to the current commit using git add? I'm using an express template + Node.JS

Comment: I added an update to my original question. Thanks for your help, Winfield! :)